# d3 button callback in appended html

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, callback

I have a d3 code section that has html.

```
var div = d3.select("body")
              .append("div")
              .attr("id", "mouseover")
              .attr("class", "decisionMenu")
              .style("opacity", 1)
              .html('
              <button type="button" onclick="doFunction();">Click Me</button>')
```

doFunction is defined like this:

```
function doFunction() {
 console.log("decision button click"); 
}
```

I would like to invoke the doFunction in the onclick callback for the button.  however, the compiler can't find doFunction since the html is in a string.  how do I make a function call when a button is clicked?

edit (I did not include this before):

I have the function being called from another function:

```
function showDecisionMenu(d) {            var g = d3.select(this); 
            var div = d3.select("body")
              .append("div")
              .attr("id", "mouseover")
              .attr("class", "decisionMenu")
              .style("opacity", 1)
              .html('<button type="button" onclick="doFunction();">Click Me</button>')
```

called from here:

```
nodeEnter.on("mouseover", showDecisionMenu)
```

Comment: Move your button onto one line. You have a multi-line string but that will only work with backticks. If you do `.html('<button type="button" onclick="doFunction();">Click Me</button>')`, the function should work fine.

Comment: I changed it to a single line but it still doesn't work

Comment: @mjpablo23 it does: https://jsfiddle.net/sczygdv9/. I'm voting to close it.

Comment: hmm, i see.  let me edit it to show the functions calling it.

Comment: It's still working: https://jsfiddle.net/bedw17vy/

Comment: ah ok, it's working now.  I had to change the context of where I defined doFunction.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using d3 anyway, you could stay in d3 for this too and do:

```
var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "mouseover")
    .attr("class", "decisionMenu")
    .style("opacity", 1);
div.append('button')
     .attr("type", "button")
     .text("Click Me")
     .on("click", doFunction);
```

Comment: is there documentation on what kinds of elements I can append in d3 using this format?  I would like to append a pull down menu also.

Comment: d3 uses [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) behind the scenes so I’m not aware of any dom elements you can’t append using d3. You should certainly be able to do a drop down menu.